# Can one inspect the weights learned by a logistic regression classifier in weka?

Tags: regression, weka, classification

I'm training Weka's logistic regression classifier and I'm trying to figure out what is going on under the hood.  I know that I can use the classifier to look at the confidence distribution per instance using the `logistic.distributionForInstance` method but is there a way that I can look at the feature weights learned by the classifier?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can get the weights as a 2D array of doubles with the [`coefficients`](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/functions/Logistic.html#coefficients%28%29) method.  The first index is for the attributes and the second index is for the classes.